# Is it usual for ASPX files to take 5-10 seconds to save?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, resharper, performance

Using Visual Studio 2008 with Resharper, is it usual for ASPX files to take a long time to save? I usually find that it takes up to about 10 seconds on an average PC (18 months old). What is it doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's more likely that the problem is your choice of anti-virus software.

There are well documented cases of some products (cough [Trend Micro](http://www.threndmicro.com) cough [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com) cough) being prone to becoming over eager and making developers life hell by agressively scanning every source file, assembly and jar whenever someone breathes.

Comment: Yes, I'm rapidly coming to the conclusion that some anti-virus products are almost as bad as the viruses that they're 'protecting' us from. Some days, our office PCs run at a snails pace, other days they're fine - I've always suspected scheduled virus scans, but there doesn't seem to be a pattern to it.

Comment: The real-time scanners of some AV products are definitely bloated. I would recommend CA and ESET, both add very little overhead.

Comment: Wow, yes it was Trend Micro... and here I've been blaming Visual Studio the whole time

Answer (score 1):

Resharper does slow things down considerably but it's not usual to take this long. If you don't use much of Resharper's functionality maybe consider using other add-ins that offer only particular functionality you actually use.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it take longer to save files when you're working directly into the IIS - when the project is on the local host (or a remote host, though I never done that one) instead of a directory.